# Openlayers4 - GoogleMaps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm new with OpenLayer.
I'm updating ol2 version with the new ol4(4.1.0).
In the earlier version GoogleMaps was already integrated, but in in the new version I cannot find a way to include it.
I saw a way using ol3 but it's not affidable.

There is a way with the new version of OpenLayer to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing has changed, it's still the same situation as with OpenLayers 3. No plans to change this, as there is no direct tile access available.